# calculate average color baseline of image using wand in python

Tags: python, image-processing, data-science, wand

i want to calculate the average color of image using wand in python. i have tried  code which can do it but that code is in "imagemagick" package and i am facing some problems with it's installation. can anybody here help me with this..i would really appreciate any help of guidance. here is the code for "imagemagick" package. i am really new to wand library.

```
convert <input.jpg> -resize 1x1\! \
-format "%[fx:int(255*r+.5)],%[fx:int(255*g+.5)],%[fx:int(255*b+.5)]" info:-
```

Comment: Have you considered using PIL/Pillow rather than wand? I believe PIL/Pillow is better maintained.

Comment: See Python Wand's fx equivalent at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html

Answer (score 1):

With [wand](/questions/tagged/wand), you already have the power of python to apply simple mathematics.

```python
with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
    img.resize(1,1)
    with img[0, 0] as color:
        r = int(255.0 * color.red + 0.5)
        g = int(255.0 * color.green + 0.5)
        b = int(255.0 * color.blue + 0.5)
    print('{0},{1},{2}'.format(r,g,b))
```

But that could be simplified further with...

```python
with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
    img.resize(1,1)
    with img[0, 0] as color:
        r = math.ceil(255 * color.red)
        g = math.ceil(255 * color.green)
        b = math.ceil(255 * color.blue)
    print('{0},{1},{2}'.format(r,g,b))
```

Or even further with...

```python
with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
    img.resize(1,1)
    with img[0, 0] as color:
        r = color.red_int8
        g = color.green_int8
        b = color.blue_int8
    print('{0},{1},{2}'.format(r,g,b))
```